# How to enable macros when "Enable all macros" reverts to the default "Disable all macros"?

Tags: vba, outlook

I tried the following steps:

**1. VBA environment**

Tools ---> Macros ---> ... Trust Centre settings don't display

**2. Outlook environment**

File ---> Options ---> Trust Centre ---> Macro settings ---> Enable all macros / Apply macro settings
After I select OK it resets to the default "Disable all macros".
When I try to Run macros in the project the follow message displays:
The macros in this project are disabled.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... here's the answer for anyone else:

Outlook environment

After you've selected File --> Options ---> Trust Centre ---> Macro Settings

... select "Notifications for all Macros" NOT "Enable all Macros"

then select Apply macro settings then OK

... every time you attempt to Run or open a file containing a macro a popup message should appear and then you should select "Enable macros...."